# CSS transitions adjustable height

Tags: jquery, css, button, html, transition

I found this [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto) and I have been trying to use this method to change the height of a div on button onclick but for some reason it is not working for me. Sorry if there is a lot of unnecessary information.

jQuery

```
function playSound(soundfile){
      document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = 
      "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}

   $('button').bind('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();

   $('.taller').toggleClass('animated');
   });
```

HTML

```
  <div id="container">
     <span id="dummy"></span>
     <button onclick="playSound('sound/button-30.wav','sound/button30.mp3');">PlaySound</button>                         
     <div class="taller">I SHOULD BECOME TALLER</div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
background-color:lightblue;
width:960px;
height:550px;
}

.taller{
overflow:hidden;
background:#000;
color:#fff;
width:80px;
max-height:15px;
-webkit-transition: max-height .5s linear;
-moz-transition: max-height .5s linear;
transition: max-height .5s linear;
}

.animated{
max-height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into a jsfiddle and tested it. It works just fine; I didn't do anything to it. You can see your code in action here http://jsfiddle.net/WY7gM/

Comment: Yes, that is what I want but for some reason it is not working in Aptana Studio or in my browser.

Comment: Do you know why this might be happening? It works fine in jsfiddle.

Comment: if you open up your debugger in either firefox or chrome, look at the console to see if there are any errors caused in any other parts of your script. It could be, the code works great but its not able to make it that because of an error.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you are using your ids more than once and the one you are expecting to use is the second (or third) one (getElementById only returns first occurrence). Beyond that, without more context or debugging through it myself, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/QXYRJ/)**

Changed it to height rather than max-height and it worked fine. On toggle it will grow/shrink. Your question is a bit vague though so I'm not sure if this is what your after. Also why not just put the playsound functionality inside the click bind?

Comment: Your right about the playsound functionality. I guess my question is more about why it is not working in my browser when I open the source file from Aptana.